# sprites are not removed - swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to remove some sprites, but not all are removed. Please check the code below.

```
    func removeSquare(squareSprite : SKNode)   {        

       for (index, value) in squares.enumerate()    {

           if Int(value.sprite.position.x) == Int(squareSprite.position.x)  {
              for i in 0..<2  {
                  if index - i >= 0  {
                    squares[index - i].sprite.removeFromParent()
                    squares.removeAtIndex(index - i)
                    print("index - i is \(index - i)")
                    print("squares.count is \(squares.count)")
                  }
              }
           }
       }
```

When `i` is greater than zero the sprite is not removed, otherwise when it's zero, it removes the sprite. 
`squares`is an array containing square sprites which have a `sprite` property of type `SKSpriteNode`. I checked the count of squares also and the number reduces appropriately, but the sprite is still on the screen.

Comment: Which sprites you whant to remove and then ?

Comment: it sounds like the indexes at squares will change since you are doing `squares.removeAtIndex(index - i)`, so i at 1 becomes 0 in the next loop,  you want to go in reverse direction 1..>=0 so that it doesnt change.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon thanks, that really helped. Also I used another variable to represent the index. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are reducing your array while iterating through it. Try to comment this line out, to check if your algorithm is working in principle and the correct sprites are removed:

```
squares.removeAtIndex(index - i)
```

If yes, change your algorithm to start at the end of the array

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the indexes at squares will change since you are doing squares.removeAtIndex(index - i), making your array smaller with each iteration, so `i` at `1` becomes `0` in the next loop, you want to go in reverse direction `1..>=0` so that the array becomes smaller without changing the indexes for the objects in the array.